# I have 3000 text files, with each reporting a time duration at the end. Is there a way in Bash to find what the maximum value was?

Tags: bash

I have 3000 text files on a linux cluster, each ending in something like

```
Run Time of 4.533 mins
```

I am wondering if there was an easy way in Bash scripting to run a loop or something similar on all these files `*.txt` and to extract the times and find what the maximum was?

Comment: Do the times sometimes include hours or days? Or is it always minutes?

Comment: It is always minutes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a file `myFile.txt` formatted like this

```
some
content
goes
here
...

Run Time of 4.533 mins
```

You can get the time with `tail -n1 myFile.txt | cut -f4 -d' '`

`tail -n1` returns the last line

`cut -d' '` cut the columns by white space

`-f4` select the forth entry

follow @Mark comment to apply it to your 3000 files

Comment: No real need for a loop, `tail -qn1 file{1..3000}` will do them all. No real need to save them in an array, just pipe them to `sort`. No real need for `cut`, as `sort` can pick a field as the key.

Comment: even better solution